# Calculate median of a row in a dataframe and save to new variable

Tags: r, dataframe, median

I have an excel file that looks like this

[image]

I load this file into R  and then I want to calculate the median of columns 1 to 6, per row and save the result in a new variable. I tried doing the following:

```
data$C_median <- median(data[1:6], na.rm=TRUE)
```

This results however in the following error:

```
Error in median.default(data[1:6], na.rm = TRUE) : need numeric data
```

I'm not sure how to solve this issue as I believe all data to already be numeric (apart from na values that are removed with na.rm = TRUE).

Note that for calculating the mean I am able to use similarly fashioned code without issue.

```
data$C_mean <- rowMeans(data[1:6], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: those are strings (including your NAs - they are not proper NAs). You need to convert them to numeric...

Comment: `apply(data[1:6], 1, median, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to calculate the median for each row through column 1 to 6, you can use `apply()` to make it

```
data$median <- apply(data[1:6],1,function(v) median(as.numeric(v),na.rm = T))
```

Note that the error you encounter indicates that you were using non-numeric type data, so you need to convert them to numeric first via `as.numeric()`

Comment: Or another option is `rowMedians(as.matrix(data[1:6]), na.rm = TRUE)` from `matrixStats`